# Unable to fetch `href` from Reddit embedded feed window using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to fetch reddit account name from reddit feed window, from the following link :

```
fetch('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ripple/')
```

Now, here I am able to fetch twitter account details successfully using following code:

```
#fetch the tweet account of coin
tweet_account = response.xpath('//a[starts-with(@href, "https://twitter.com")]/@href').extract()
tweet_account = [s for s in tweet_account if s != 'https://twitter.com/CoinMarketCap']
tweet_account = [s for s in tweet_account if len(s) < 60 ]
print(tweet_account)
```

However, I am not able to get reddit account using similar method ??

```
reddit_account = response.xpath('//a[starts-with(@href, "https://www.reddit.com")]/@href').extract()
reddit_account = [s for s in reddit_account if s != 'https://www.reddit.com/r/CoinMarketCap'']
reddit_account = [s for s in reddit_account if len(s) < 60 ]
print(reddit_account)
```

Even I have tried fetching directly using simple xpath but it doesn't work :

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="reddit"]/div/div[1]/h4/a[2]/@href')
```

Output for :

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="reddit"]').extract()
```

shows

```
<b>['<div id="reddit" class="col-sm-6 text-left">\n</div>']</b>
```

But there are many more tags inside this div tag?? why am I not able to get those tags??

Unfortunately, Scrapy is unable to find what is inside this div. This reddit feed even doesn't have an iframe. Is there any separate URL I should be calling??

Edit<\b> :

I did show(response) in shell. and it have twitter data but not reddit ?? why it should be ?

Comment: Hi, This problem is actually not reproducible. All the 3 xpath you have provided are returning something for me. What is your `response.status`

Comment: Thanks for reply 
My response is following
>>> fetch('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ripple/')
2019-03-25 12:45:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ripple/> (referer: None)
>>> response
<200 https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ripple/>

Comment: my desired output is reddit_account = ['https://www.reddit.com/r/Ripple/'] @DirtyBit

Comment: Can you check code if it returns reddit_account = ['reddit.com/r/Ripple/']  ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All data won't be in the page source as shown in the website. If you are using google chrome browser please press ctrl+u to see the page source then ctrl+f to search for the data that you want. If it's not in the page source you may have to send some other requests to get the data.

Comment: Thanks for reply. That's correct I did view(response) and reddit feed is not there. But i don't know that what extra request I should send ?? can you please guide ?

Comment: What do you want to scrape? Please elaborate

Comment: on this page : https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ripple/ , there is reddit feed window under social tab. I want to fetch Reddit link like :  ['www.reddit.com/r/Ripple/']

Comment: okay, you check the url you want to get by inspecting on your browser(right click-->inspect), then copy the url and search it in the view response page

Comment: if the url is seen anywhere in the view response page, you can build an xpath from there.

Comment: dude, yes I can see the URL in page source , I build the xpath response.xpath('//*[@id="reddit"]/div/div[1]/h4/a[2]/@href') but that is not working and that is why I posted the question. Hope you have read my question ???

Comment: try this xpath '//a[@title="Reddit"]/@href'

Comment: No dude it's not working, you understood my issue right ?? I want this link ['https://www.reddit.com/r/Ripple/']  from the page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190617/discussion-between-agus-mathew-and-priya-kumari).

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55346802/get-text-inside-a-span-class-of-a-particular-div

Comment: Yes I got it. As that href is coming from javascript , I could not fetch that. I have to use other framework like selenium. Thanks

Comment: @priyakumari okay, can you mark this as the answer, i see many similar doubts here